# Url Mapping in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

My GWT project is not working  when im trying to run my [project]_build.xml as ant.

This is my web.xml file :

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>gwtTest</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>es.gwt.finalTest.server.TestServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>gwtTest</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the Remote Service Path found at My Service.java
`@RemoteServiceRelativePath("test")`

Plus when i remove this : `private GreetingServiceAsync messageService =  GWT.create(GreetingService.class);`  from my EntryPoint the error doesnt occur anymore but of course i have no access to my servlet

Comment: BUILD FAILED
D:\home\eclipse_workspace\ESHEAD\apps\gwt\finalTest_build.xml:19: Java returned: 1

Comment: And it doesn't print anything else before that line?

Comment: [java] Loading inherited module 'es.gwt.finalTest.finalTest'
 [java]    [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
 [java] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the  "url-pattern" tag should look more like

```
 <url-pattern>/yourApp/test</url-pattern>
```